# Executing SQL Commands from a WIx Bootstrapper

Tags: wix

I am trying to create an sql database and execute some sql commands setting it up in my WIx bootstrapper.  I have been able to install SQL 2014 Express int eh bootstrapper but am struggling to find the right way to package sql commands in the chain.  I could add the sql commands to a product, but I would prefer to do it in the bootstrapper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Burn installs packages. It's not an installation engine, so there's no support for things like SQL. For that, WiX provides the SQL extension in .msi packages.